# How to localize random text swift

Tags: ios, swift, random, localization

I have this in a `model.swift` file (together with the answers array):

```
func getAnswer() -> String {
    var random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(answers.count)))

    let result = answers[random]
    return result
}
```

and this in my view controller:

```
@IBAction func getAnswerTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    answerText.text = model.getAnswer()
    answerText.text = NSLocalizedString("Of course I do...", comment: "")
    answerText.hidden = false
}
```

This is accessing the `localizable.string` file as it translates the phrase correctly when I run the app though I can't work out how to localize the randomly generated phrase from the answers array listed in the `model.swift` file.

What should this line be to do that?

```
answerText.text = NSLocalizedString("Of course I do...", comment: "")
```

Should it be something like:

```
answerText.text = (NSLocalizedString("%@",comment: ""), SOMETHINGGOESHERE))
```

Comment: Is the answers array a list of hard-coded Strings?

Comment: They're like this :

        var answers = [
        "Of course I do...",
        "You're kidding, right...?",
        "That's the wrong question",
        "In your dreams maybe",
        "Seriously?",
      ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `answers` is an array of hard-coded Strings, then just do this:

```
let answers = [NSLocalizedString("answer1", comment = "ans1"), NSLocalizedString("answer2", comment = "ans2"), NSLocalizedString("answer3", comment = "ans3")]
```

Then just call it as any other String.

Comment: Ah, there's a pretty long list, that was only part of it I pasted there. Is there no way to be able to call the randomized answer translation from the localizable.strings file without copying 100 phrases out?

Comment: Works great. Thanks, D.Greg!

Comment: If you find one, let me know. lol. I just this with an app recently. I'm glad it works for you.

Comment: Yeah, will do. I tend to move on quickly though if I find a reasonable fix, which is not great, I admit. Working now on making the launch screen show the localization (which is just not showing) and then onto the bundle display name...

Comment: Good luck. It seems like you've got a lot of work ahead of you.

Comment: Relative newbie though having a ball. Good luck to you too. Hope our paths cross again. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Anytime. Have fun with your app.